# Is there a relationship between force and entropy?

Tags: entropy, strong-force, weak-interaction

1. Is there any relation between force and entropy? If any, I would like to know what the equation of this relation will be.
2. What is the entropy of strong and weak nuclear force? Can we determine it? If so, what will be the equation of the strong and weak nuclear force entropy?

Comment: Q!: Have you read the [Wikipedia article on entropic forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_force)? Q2: The strong and weak forces are not entropic.

Comment: I have read it, and I already have the answer :) No, both of them are assumed to be entropic according to Freud; see it on wikipedia article on entropic forces, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.4147v1.pdf. Thus, the entropy of those forces can possibly be counted. But how?

Comment: That paper points out that Yang-Mills forces could be entropic. However this is entirely speculation and there is absolutely no evidence that the strong and weak forces are entropic in nature.

Comment: @Yohanes Nuwara : fear++ ; it is Peter G.O. Freund ( Enrico Fermi Institute and Department of Physics Chicago U.) and not Freud AKA Dr Sigmund ...